# PHP + space issue

Tags: php

I want to get the number of spaces added before a word.

For example

```
String 1 = Hello 
String 2 =    Server.
```

In String 2 there are four spaces before `Server`. when I concatenate string 1 and string2 I loose the spaces.

Basically space should be treated as a character. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You don't lose your spaces in a concatenation:

```
$s1 = 'Hello';
$s2 = '    Server';

print_r($s1.$s2);
```

Outputs

```
Hello    Server
```

http://ideone.com/PmHOQ

Answer (score 2):

To avoid losing your spaces, try to echo the string in a

```
<pre></pre>
```

Html tag (or simply check it with var_dump or in the html source).

Comment: How did you figure out he was talking about HTML output?

Comment: It's a common question :) and console,file etc output shows the whitespaces.

Comment: Another easy way to tell the browser to display repeated spaces is to replace them with the &nbsp; non-breaking space character. i.e.: `str_replace('  ', ' &nbsp;', $string)`

Comment: common question? then why don't you flag it as a duplicate?

Comment: @zaf Common question from beginners. flag it if you want. cheers

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're having problems with html collapsing spaces. You just need to replace with non breakable spaces.

You could do that:

calculate how many spaces are in front:

```
$diff = strlen($s2) - strlen(ltrim($s2,' '));
```

prefix the trimmed string with non breakable spaces:

```
$s2 = str_repeat('&nbsp;', $diff) . ltrim($s2,' ');
```

*Alternatively, you could use strtr to replace all `' '` into `'&nbsp;'`*